# Replace string elements in pandas Index object

Tags: string, python-3.x, pandas, indexing, replace

I have a very simple problem, but cannot find an answer. I have a pandas Index object containing strings ('string_index'). I want to replace certain elements, by preferrably a dictionary, in this string Index

```
 [In:] string_index
 [Out:] Index(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], dtype='object')

 exchange_dict = {'A':'Y', 'B':'Z'}
```

But trying

```
 string_index.rename(exchange_dict)
```

does not work and method .replace is not possible. How can I do that?

To get 'string_index' here as example:

```
 string_list=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
 stringer = pd.DataFrame(string_list, index=string_list)
 string_index = stringer.index
```

**Please note: 'stringer_list' and 'stringer' are not part of the challenge, I only created to give you a working example. In my real example I only have 'string_index'.** I suppose there is a very easy solution, I am too dumb to find?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mention `index` in `rename`

```
stringer.rename(index=exchange_dict)
Out[557]: 
   0
Y  A
Z  B
C  C
D  D
E  E
F  F
```

Update

```
pd.Index(string_index.to_series().replace(exchange_dict))
Out[570]: Index(['Y', 'Z', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: please note: I need to do that on 'stringer_index'. 'stringer' is not available. I created only here, that you get an working example.

Comment: Thank you! Great As I thought, might be very easy with some aux conversion